# HIVE QUERY SELECT * FROM bookfreq where freq IN (SELECT Max(freq) FROM bookfreq);

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am writing hive query,for fetching record has maximum freq value.

```
table name bookfreq, having two column year & freq

year freq

1999  2

2000  4

1989  4

1990  5
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM bookfreq where freq IN (SELECT Max(freq) FROM bookfreq);
```

I am getting an exception like

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:38 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'Max' '(' in expression specification
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Hive 0.13 or later (as documented [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)), this type of subquery should be possible.  However, the column names still have to be fully qualified.  So, to do what I think you want to do in Hive 0.13 or beyond it would be

```
SELECT * FROM bookfreq a
WHERE a.freq IN (SELECT max(b.freq) FROM bookfreq b);
```

If you have an older version of Hive, you can try this notation:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM bookfreq a JOIN (SELECT max(freq) as max_freq FROM bookfreq) b
  ON a.freq = b.max_freq;
```

If that still does not work (which would probably mean your version of Hive is quite out of date), you may have to actually create the table containing `max(freq)` as a concrete object first:

```
CREATE TABLE b AS SELECT max(freq) AS max_freq FROM bookfreq;
```

And then run the above query using plain `b`.  Something like:

```
SELECT bookfreq.*
FROM bookfreq JOIN b ON bookfreq.freq = b.max_freq;
```

Comment: Thanks. rchang  :-) for your quick respose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an alias to any subquery in hive.

Try adding an alias to your subquery such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM bookfreq where freq IN (SELECT Max(freq) FROM bookfreq) a;
```

Just a preference here, but I prefer to write it as follows:

```
select * from (select max(freq) as max_freq from bookfreq) a join bookfreq b on a.max_freq = b.freq;
```